# NIFI Reading XML node value

Tags: apache-nifi

I have the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><ns1:SalesOrderMessages mlns:ns1="http://corpintra.net/pi/CBFC_GLOBAL_SAP_APPL/SalesOrder" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
         <SalesOrder>
            <MessageProcessingInformation>
               <SendingSystemID>SMS_0175</SendingSystemID>
            </MessageProcessingInformation>
            <Header>
               <SalesDocumentType>YPO0</SalesDocumentType>
               <SalesOrganization>7002</SalesOrganization>
               <DistributionChannel>00</DistributionChannel>
               <RequestedDeliveryDate>2023-06-15</RequestedDeliveryDate>
               <CustomerPurchaseOrderDate>2023-06-15</CustomerPurchaseOrderDate>
               <Incoterms1>EXW</Incoterms1>
               <Incoterms2>Ex Works</Incoterms2>
               <PaymentTerms>E007</PaymentTerms>
               <CustomerPurchaseOrderNumber>990831 </CustomerPurchaseOrderNumber>
               <ReferenceDocumentNumber>SI-000000614</ReferenceDocumentNumber>
               <ServicesRenderedDate>2023-06-15</ServicesRenderedDate>
               <LogisticData>
                  <SourceReferenceDocumentNumber>SI-000000614</SourceReferenceDocumentNumber>
                  <SourceSalesOrderNumber>SO-000050562</SourceSalesOrderNumber>
               </LogisticData>
            </Header>
            <Items>
               <ItemNumber>10</ItemNumber>
                   ............
```

I need to read the node value  "ReferenceDocumentNumber", which is "SI-000000614"

I am using EvaluateXpath processor in Nifi. And my setting is attached in the image[image]

I had even tried with /@ReferenceDocument. But not getting the node value. Please help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed the root element `ns1:SalesOrderMessages`. This works for me:

**Input**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns1:SalesOrderMessages mlns:ns1="http://corpintra.net/pi/CBFC_GLOBAL_SAP_APPL/SalesOrder" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
         <SalesOrder>
            <MessageProcessingInformation>
               <SendingSystemID>SMS_0175</SendingSystemID>
            </MessageProcessingInformation>
            <Header>
               <SalesDocumentType>YPO0</SalesDocumentType>
               <SalesOrganization>7002</SalesOrganization>
               <DistributionChannel>00</DistributionChannel>
               <RequestedDeliveryDate>2023-06-15</RequestedDeliveryDate>
               <CustomerPurchaseOrderDate>2023-06-15</CustomerPurchaseOrderDate>
               <Incoterms1>EXW</Incoterms1>
               <Incoterms2>Ex Works</Incoterms2>
               <PaymentTerms>E007</PaymentTerms>
               <CustomerPurchaseOrderNumber>990831 </CustomerPurchaseOrderNumber>
               <ReferenceDocumentNumber>SI-000000614</ReferenceDocumentNumber>
               <ServicesRenderedDate>2023-06-15</ServicesRenderedDate>
               <LogisticData>
                  <SourceReferenceDocumentNumber>SI-000000614</SourceReferenceDocumentNumber>
                  <SourceSalesOrderNumber>SO-000050562</SourceSalesOrderNumber>
               </LogisticData>
            </Header>
</SalesOrder>
</ns1:SalesOrderMessages>
```

**Xpath Expression**

```
/*:SalesOrderMessages/SalesOrder/Header/ReferenceDocumentNumber
```

or

```
//ReferenceDocumentNumber
```

**Output**

```
SI-000000614
```